# Modifying lines of text in Python and keeping track of it

Tags: python

I have a string of text in python which consists of multiple words and parentheses. Example:

```
(the)boy(went(home(yesterday)
```

I want to use a python statement to insert a space before each opening parenthesis and another one after each closing parenthesis. This would be my desired output:

```
 (the) boy (went (home (yesterday)
```

In addition to that, I have a variable called `parenthesis_status` whose initial value is 0, and I would like it to increment by 1 for each opening parenthesis and decrease by 1 for each closing parenthesis.

How could I do this? I thought of iterating over the string of characters, though I don't know how to modify it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your string of text is stored in variable `s`,

```
s.replace('(', ' (').replace(')', ') ')
```

would return:

```
 (the) boy (went (home (yesterday)
```

And to count parentheses:

```
parenthesis_status = s.count('(') - s.count(')')
```

`parenthesis_status` would become: 2

Comment: Thanks! And how could I do the `parenthesis_status` thing?

Comment: Don't forget to accept this answer if it's what you want (it seems to be).

Answer (score 0):

Try it out:

```
x = "(the)boy(went(home(yesterday)"
s = x.replace("(", "( ").replace(")", ") ")
parenthesis_status = x.count("(") - x.count(")")
```

Comment: @EL_DON yep, fix'd